# RegExp: how to exclude matched groups from $N?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I've made a working regexp, but i think it's not the best use-case:

```
el = '<div style="color:red">123</div>';
el.replace(/(<div.*>)(\d+)(<\/div>)/g, '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
// expecting result: <div style="color:red"><b>123</b></div>
```

After googling i've found that `(?: ... )` in regexps - means ignoring group match, thus:

```
el.replace(/(?:<div.*>)(\d+)(?:<\/div>)/g, '<b>$1</b>');
// returns <b>123</b>
```

but i need an expecting result from 1st example.

Is there a way to exclude 'em? just to write `replace(/.../, '<b>$1</b>')`?

This is just a little case for understanding how to exclude groups in regexp. And i *know*, what [we can't parse HTML with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) :)

Comment: Nope, you can't do that. `.replace` will substitute the whole match.

Comment: No chance to do that via the DOM?

Comment: DOM isn't an aim. Just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to get the same result while only using the replacement `<b>$1</b>`?

In your case just `replace(/\d+/, '<b>$&</b>')` would suffice.

But if you want to make sure there are div tags around the number, you could use lookarounds and `\K` like in the following expression. Except that JS does **not** support lookbehind nor `\K`, so you're out of luck, you have to use a capturing group for that in JS.

```
<div[^>]*>\K\d+(?=</div>)
```

Comment: Oops, i've mispelled. `el.replace(/(?:<div.*>)(\d+)(?:<\/div>)/g, '<b>$1</b>');` returns just `<b>123</b>`

Comment: Yes, the aim is to match digits around specified tag. That's sad js doesn't support `\K`

Comment: Hmm, this `'<div style="color:red">123</div><div>555</div>'.replace(/(?!<div.*>)(\d+)(?=<\/div>)/g, '<i>$1</i>')` is working (result: `"<div style="color:red"><i>123</i></div><div><i>555</i></div>"`). But i dont understand why it's working, since `(?!` means negative lookahead. `(?<=` doesn't work.

Comment: @mjey it's working because `\d+` is working. Try it on the string `123</div>`. *Negative* lookahead means whatever is ahead should **not** match the expression.

Comment: Okay, understood. But as you can see, positive lookahead works (chrome 18) :)

Answer (score 0):

There nothing wrong with a replacement value of `'$1<b>$2</b>$3'`.  I would just change your regex to this:

```
el = '<div style="color:red">123</div>';
el.replace(/(<div[^>]*>)(\d+)(<\/div>)/g, '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
```

Changing how it matches the first div keeps the full match on the div tags, but makes sure it matches the minimum possible before the closing `>` of the first div tag rather than the maximum possible.

With your regex, you would not get what you wanted with this input string:

```
el = '<div style="color:red">123</div><div style="color:red">456</div>';
```

---

The problem with using something like:

```
el.replace(/\d+/, '<b>$&</b>')
```

is that doesn't work properly with things like this:

```
el = '<div style="margin-left: 10px">123</div>'
```

because it picks up the numbers inside the div tag.

Comment: *"it matches the minimum possible before the closing >"* that may not work as you think. In `<div>x</div><div>123</div>` `$1` would capture `<div>x</div><div>`, as in OPs original expression.

Comment: @Qtax - I've modified my regex to make it more foolproof in that regard.